# Simple use of "import as" to load multi-scenario data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variable-assignment, python-import

I receive scenario data (identical sets of variables with different values by scenario) in the form of python modules.

Example:

`scen00.py`:

```
scenario_name = ["foo"]
scenario_num = [0]
.
.
```

`scen01.py`:

```
scenario_name = ["bar"]
scenario_num = [1]
.
.
```

I import each scenario to a separate incidence of a python function using `import as`, and then do all of the programming, referencing the base namespace.

Example:

```
import sys

def main():

    script = sys.argv[0]
    no_scens = int(sys.argv[1])

    for i in range(0, no_scens):
        process_1(i)

def process_1(scen_count):

    if scen_count == 0:
        import scen00
    elif scen_count == 1:
        import scen01 as scen00

    print(scen00.scenario_name[0], scen00.scenario_num[0])
```

Expected Outcome:

```
foo 0
bar 1
```

While this code works when `no_scens` is `2`, the segment in `process_1()` which assigns the different scenarios to `scen00` is not scalable and inelegant. Assuming I now have 150 scenarios to import, how could I best modify `process_1()`?

Comment: The question marked as duplicate appears not to reference namespaces. How can I make that more clear in my question?

Comment: What do you call *namespaces*? If it is the ability to reference the newly imported module with a name (which is **not** what the Python doc calls namespace), then you can simply do: `def process(scen_count): name = "scen{}".format(scen_count) mod = importlib.import_module(name) print(mod.scenario_name[0], mod.scenario_num[0] )` (partially present in one of the answers of the duplicate)

Comment: What you pointed out was as important as the import code (and as is the duplicate answer indicates, more version-appropriate than using __import__). As a first-time poster, I would have found it difficult to get my full answer from the duplicate, without your and msaba92's insight.

Answer (score 2):

You could try variable import:

```
def process_1(scen_count):
    scen = __import__("scen%02d" % scen_count)
    print(scen.scenario_name[0], scen.scenario_name[1])
```